# How can I display two images horizontally?

Tags: php, css

I have a problem and needed an answer. How can I automatically put the 2 images horizontally.

I think I will use some if(1 ==%3)?
In the example pic I really like to horizontal the 2 images  don't know how to do it ?

Here's what I've done:

```
for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){
    if($dsds=='Commissoner'){
    echo $rows['prog_id'].$rows['prog_id'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$rows['prog_name'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$rows['votes'];

    }else {
//this is the part where I put a css
    style='margin-left:44px;'><div class='box_img2' style='margin-right:10px;' >";
    echo '<img src="candidates/images/'.$rows['image'].'" width="70" height="80px" />'.',&nbsp;'.'<br>'.$rows['lastname'].',&nbsp;'.$rows['firstname'].'<br>'.'&nbsp;=&nbsp;'.$rows['votes'];
    echo '<br>';
            }
    $sdsd=$dsada    
        ?>
        <img  src="candidates/images/percent.gif"width='<?php echo(100*round($rows['votes']/($sdsd),2)); ?>'height='10'>
        <?php 
            if ($rows['votes']==0){
        echo "<br>";}
            else {
            echo(100*round($rows['votes']/($sdsd),2)); ?>%<br>
                        <?php
                            }
                            echo '</div>';
                        }

                        ?>
```

[image: Sample of my problem]

Here's my css:

```
.row:before, .row:after { clear:both; }
.row{
 display: block;

}

.box_img2 {
        float: left;
        /*margin-right:85px;*/
        text-align:center;
    }
    .box_img2 img { /* if you want it centered */
     display:block;

        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Here's my entire codes:

```
<?php
      include('../connection/connect.php');
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candposition ORDER BY posid ASC");
                $result->bindParam(':userid', $res);
                $result->execute();
                for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
                $dsds=$row['posid'];
                $resulta = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(votes) FROM candidates WHERE posid= :a");
                $resulta->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
                $resulta->execute();
                for($i=0; $rowa = $resulta->fetch(); $i++){
                    $dsada=$rowa['sum(votes)'];
                }
                    echo '<div style="margin-top: 18px;">';
                    echo '<strong>'.$row['pos_name'].'&nbsp;'.'</strong><br>';

                    $results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates,student WHERE candidates.idno=student.idno AND candidates.syearid = '$no'AND posid = :a ORDER BY votes DESC");
                    $results->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
                    $results->execute();
                    for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){
                        if($dsds=='Commissoner'){
                        echo $rows['prog_id'].$rows['prog_id'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$rows['prog_name'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$rows['votes'];
                                }else {

//this is the part 
                            echo'<?php $src=array("candidates/images/".$rows["image"]); for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){ ?>';
                            echo '<img src="candidates/images<?php echo .$src[$i];?>" class="image-inner" />';}
                        $sdsd=$dsada    
                            ?>
        <!--    <img  src="candidates/images/percent.gif"width='<?php echo(100*round($rows['votes']/($sdsd),2)); ?>'height='10'>-->
                    <?php 
                        if ($rows['votes']==0){
                            echo "<br>";}
                                else {
                            //  echo(100*round($rows['votes']/($sdsd),2)); /
                            /*?>%<br>*/
    /*<?php
                            }
                            echo '</div>';*/
                        }
                        }
                        ?>  
                        <?php
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Just give 'position : relative;' in css and give some width to images

Comment: where should I put that? in row?

Comment: Here is a fiddle for you.. https://jsfiddle.net/adarsmohan76/cdvsw8hz/

Comment: What if I'm calling it to the php

Comment: Both are same, even if you are using php, it will appear as html tags for client side..

Comment: Is it okey if I'm using for loop?

Comment: Yes that will work fine.. But make sure that the tags are clearly closed.(including the double/single quotes)

Comment: where should I put the for loop at top of  echo '<img src="candidates/images/'.$rows['image'].'" width="70" height="80px" />'.',&nbsp;'.'<br>'.$rows['lastname'].',&nbsp;'.$rows['firstname'].'<br>'.'&nbsp;=&nbsp;'.$rows['votes'];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100734/discussion-between-adarsh-mohan-and-miming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest way i can explain using php. Hopes this will help you to understand

```css
.image-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<?php
  $src = array(
    'http://www.google.com/logos/2008/de_doodle4google08.gif', 
    'http://www.google.com/logos/2012/d4g_poland12-hp.jpg', 
    'http://www.google.com/logos/2011/colombia-independenceday11-hp.jpg'
  );
  for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
  {
    echo "<img src='{$src[$i]}' class='image-inner' />";
  }
?>
```

Comment: sir? where should I put "candidates/images/'.$rows['image'].'??

Comment: U might place them like <?php echo '<img src="candidates/images/'.$row['image'].'" class="someclassname" />'; ?>

Comment: There are different ways to output in php. You can either use echo to output img tag or directly use them by closing the php tag and typing the img tag as usual

Comment: echo'<?php $src=array("candidates/images/".$rows["image"]); for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){ ?>';
 echo '<?php <img src="candidates/images/'.$rows['image'].'" class="image-inner" />';
 echo '<img src="<?php echo $src[$i];?>" class="image-inner" />'; I try this but my image can't show?

Comment: Use some ide for code editing. You are doing the codes in the wrong way.. Atleast use some code highlighting tools like dreamviewer, sublime, npp

Comment: `echo '<img src="candidates/images<?php echo $src[$i];?>" class="image-inner" />'; `I've just add this but no picture will shown

Comment: I have to echo because it this code was inside in a php before I call the images

Comment: You have to add the src array also.. Its working fine for me.. I have tested and then posted

Comment: `echo'<?php $src=array("candidates/images/".$rows["image"]); for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){ ?>';
 echo '<img src="candidates/images<?php echo .$src[$i];?>" class="image-inner" />';` I have called the folder that I putted my images but it doesn't show

Comment: Dont echo the entire php code.. You dont have to echo the answer again.. Copy the post to a new file as somefile.php and run it.. U ll get the solution

Answer (score 1):

Display the `divs` as `inline-block` like so :

```
#christmas_promotion_boxes div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tDfCR/153/)

Comment: what if I'm calling the images in php?